# Read hex from file (Python)

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a file, that contains both hex data and non-hex data.
For example, `var _0x36ba=["\x69\x73\x41\x72\x72\x61\x79","\x63\x61\x6C\x6C","\x74\x6F\x53\x74\x72\x69\x6E\x67",]`

When I directly paste this code in python console, I got `var _0x36ba=["isArray","call","toString",]`

But when I try to read the file and print contents, it gives me `var _0x36ba=["\\x69\\x73\\x41\\x72\\x72\\x61\\x79","\\x63\\x61\\x6C\\x6C","\\x74\\x6F\\x53\\x74\\x72\\x69\\x6E\\x67","\\`

Seems like backslashes are parsed as they are.

How can I read the file and obtain readable output?

Comment: Make up your mind on what you want.  Do you want to *interprete* the hex sequences, i. e. all occurrences of `\xnn` where `n` is a hex digit?  That coul be done using a clever regexp substitution (or probably using a library doing just this).

Comment: Yes, I want to subsitute all \xnn with readable. How can I do this? After reading from file, `\\` becomes a separate symbol.

Comment: use stdlib's `binascii` library

Comment: when I use binascii.unhexlify, it says TypeError: non-hexadimal symbol found.

Comment: `unhexlify()` doesn't do what you want, it expects a different input.  Try my regexp.  That works.

Comment: Yes, seems to be working. Thank you.

Comment: **How** are you reading this from a file? You could just decode this as string literals: `value.decode('string_escape')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Please use Martijn's solution.  I didn't know the `text.decode('string_escape')` yet, and of course it is way faster.  Below follows my original answer.

Use this regular expression to unescape all escaped hexadecimal expressions within the string:

```
def unescape(text):
    return re.sub(r'\\\\|\\x([0-9a-fA-F]{2})',
        lambda m: chr(int(m.group(1), 16)) if m.group(1)
                  else '\\', text)
```

If you know that the input will not contain a double backslash followed by an `x` (e. g. `foo bar \\x41 bloh` which probably should be interpreted to  `foo bar \x41 bloh` instead of to `foo bar \A bloh`), then you can simplify this to:

```
def unescape(text):
    return re.sub(r'\\x([0-9a-fA-F]{2})',
        lambda m: chr(int(m.group(1), 16)), text)
```

Comment: This is a really slow option when you could just decode the escape syntax using a built-in codec..

Comment: Absolutely right, Martijn.  I just wasn't aware of the `.decode('string_escape')` yet.  But I was faster by several minutes in answering.  Andrew needs to decode lots of very long strings using my slow solution to sum up to these lost minutes ;-)

Comment: The price of answering while commuting. Pity we only help the OP with this solution, eh? ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You have string literals with `\xhh` hex escapes. You can decode these with the `string_escape` encoding:

```
text.decode('string_escape')
```

See the [*Python Specific Encodings* section](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#python-specific-encodings) of the `codecs` module documentation:

> `string_escape`
>   Produce a string that is suitable as string literal in Python source code

Decoding reverses that encoding:

```
>>> "\\x69\\x73\\x41\\x72\\x72\\x61\\x79".decode('string_escape')
'isArray'
>>> "\\x63\\x61\\x6C\\x6C".decode('string_escape')
'call'
>>> "\\x74\\x6F\\x53\\x74\\x72\\x69\\x6E\\x67".decode('string_escape')
'toString'
```

Being a built-in codec, this is a lot faster than using regular expressions:

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> import re
>>> def unescape(text):
...     return re.sub(r'\\x([0-9a-fA-F]{2})',
...         lambda m: chr(int(m.group(1), 16)), text)
...
>>> value = "\\x69\\x73\\x41\\x72\\x72\\x61\\x79"
>>> timeit('unescape(value)', 'from __main__ import unescape, value')
6.254786968231201
>>> timeit('value.decode("string_escape")', 'from __main__ import value')
0.43862390518188477
```

That's about 14 times faster.